# Why use 'redirect=true' in struts 1.* forward?

Tags: struts

I've been having some problems with `ActionMessages` created during execution of an action which didn't display, and I found out that my problems were due to my forwards having `redirect=true` in struts-config.xml.

Since the default behavior is `redirect=false`, I've been thinking about which benefits can one have using `redirect=true` and I couldn't find any answer. Does anyone know when and why `redirect=true` should be used in action forwards?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

it prevents the 'double submit problem'

**Never show pages in response to POST**

**Always load pages using GET**

**Navigate from POST to GET using REDIRECT**

more on this [here](https://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post) and [here](https://www.theserverside.com/news/1365142/Redirect-After-Post-2)

Comment: Seems links URLs have been updated:  [here](https://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post) and [here](https://www.theserverside.com/news/1365142/Redirect-After-Post-2)

Answer (score 28):

Redirect sends a response to the browser that forces the browser to make a new request. From the server point of view, the browser just makes a new request (albeit autmatically). Some characteristics of a redirect:

- The existing parameters and
  attributes are disposed, a new
  request is formed with the parameters
  you specify in the URL.
- The new URL
  is visible in the browser, the user
  can bookmark it.
- It takes a trip to
  the browser and back, so it can be
  slower.

A forward happens on the server. The browser is not involved in this. Some characteristics of the forward:

- New parameters are added or overwrite existing parameters. So the existing parameters cannot be removed from the request.
- Stuff can be added in request context, it will remain available. You can pass information in this way.
- The URL is not changed in the browser, for the browser the original address remains intact.
- You can only forward to another URL in the same application.

So it depends on what you want to accomplish. A forward is generally spoken faster. But if the user should be able to bookmark the new location, it is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify 
`redirect="true"`, Struts uses a client-side redirect [`response.sendRedirect()`]. The JSP will be invoked by a new browser request, and any data stored in the old request will be lost.