# Need understanding about struts-config.xml file

Tags: java, struts-config, struts-1

Let's say i have a struts-config.xml file, putting action tag only :

```
</action>
            <action path="/import"
                type="com.app.console.CSVAction"
                    scope="session"
                    name="formName"
                    input="/example.jsp"
                    validate="true">
            <forward name="success" path="/myAction.do?subAction=import"/>
 </action>
```

1. What is the role of path attribute, will it call reset method of
   myAction also.
2. What if i put redirect parameter to true.

I am asking this question because in my code.. the actionform is getting reset always(where all bean properties will be reset) corresponding to myAction.do, when i call the action **myAction.do**  above.

Please provide the detailed explanation.

Comment: Redirect is required because you reference an action in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `path` attribute defines the URL of the action.
- Why would it call an arbitrarily-named action method?!
- Oh you mean your action *form*. `reset` is *always* called by the framework, as per the documentation. Reset is almost only for initial checkbox values to work around how HTTP/clients handle unchecked checkboxes.
- It will redirect to the forward.

Please consider reading some Struts 1 documentation.

Comment: .i have read the documentation of Struts1. But still in confusion .. the Statemnt :  **Reset is almost only for initial checkbox values.** Is this related to -> <html:checkboxes> tags

Comment: Why it redirect? It forwards. Why struts1 doesn't have redirect tag?

Comment: @RomanC The "redirect" attribute in forward elements... redirects, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885967/redirect-or-forward or as described in the docs. OP asked what if redirect is used, that's what it'll do: redirect. Why? Ask the original devs.

Comment: If you do redirect, it's right way. Who is original dev? Anyway moving to S2 is a right way. Forward is not a redirect, even in servlet terms. If the framework is based on configuration (flow) it should provide the user freedom to provide the flow their way end user want with an ability to describe a domain in terms suitable in their domain.

Comment: @RomanC If you want to redirect using the Struts 1 XML configuration you set the "redirect" attribute in the `<forward>` element. That's how the framework works, and how it worked from S1.1-S1.3. That *does* provide the ability for the dev to decide whether to forward or redirect without resorting to low-level HTTP or JS, and it does so in the domain of the S1 configuration, which is the point of the S1 configuration. Ted Husted was the original S1 developer, although I don't know if he created the well-documented "redirect" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify ***redirect="true",*** Struts uses a client-side redirect [

> response.sendRedirect()].

The JSP will be invoked by a new browser request, and any data stored in the old request will be lost.